# Titanium Alloy ImageView from applicationDataDirectory

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy, alloy-ui

I am developing an app that needs to function in an offline mode.
The app has a shop for which I have to download and store product images.
In the 'shop view' I have a collection of products in a ListView.
How can I bind the downloaded images to the alloy ImageView?
The downloaded images are in the applicationDataDirectory.
So somehow I need to be able to access applicationDataDirectory in the Alloy xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `transform` function of the Collection (https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Alloy_allOS_en/page/alloy_collection_and_model_objects.html). There I would check if you are in offline/online mode and change the image path (e.g. online images with URL vs. local images with `Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + "image-name.jpg"`)

Comment: ok so I now have the path coming back from the transform method on the model
it is the absolute path (/Users/cfradley/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0A8C7B0-7F19-49AA-81B0-4099DEBF7494/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C52FC904-82DC-4137-88D1-1E5889A42430/Documents/productImages/MKC111AL710.jpg) which doesn't seem to be useful in the alloy ImageView tag as image attribute. I can only see the image placeholder. <ImageView image="{ image }" /> in the view 
what is the correct path for the image attribute ?

Comment: why, this is a correct path for a simluator image. Did you try it? Just set it to the model again and it should display. In your transform function you return the model and there you just set the image to the new path (see this tutorial https://medium.com/all-titanium/enhancing-titanium-how-to-set-up-collections-with-databinding-39573cd30911). And `image` accepts blobs and paths as a string!

Comment: omg yes thank you I just had a syntax error correct answer obviously thanx!